# Best way to transpose nested arrays within array than a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, transpose

I have an numpy array of shape `(43200, 28, 28)`, which contains 43200 images of size 28x28.
I'd like to transpose each of these images but can't find a better way to do it than with a loop such as

```
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
  arr[i] = arr[i].T
```

Is there a more efficient way ?

Comment: Don't forget to read the `np.transpose` docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can preserve the `0` axis, but transpose the latter two

```
arr.transpose(0, 2, 1)
```